# jenkins cobertura plugin conflicting names

Tags: python, django, jenkins, cobertura

I'm using Cobertura plugin for jenkins, to show the coverage of a Django project, but i have a small problem. One of my apps is called 'api', so when i click in results to that app, it goes for Cobertura REST API information.

There is any solution for this without change the name of the app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just noticed, is not just with Covertura REST API Information but Jenkins API information itself...